# How to get a RESTful api consumed by javascipt code using c#

Tags: c#, rest

I am working on a web service project using c# that needs to detect a RESTful api call from the javascript code extracted from a given html string.

I need to parse the js code and analyze it to get the RESTful api to build a call for it later using c#.

I have read about converting js code into c# classes and found tools like Jurrasic but it does not do what I need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us an example of the input/output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: input: javascript code
output: RESTful api that was called using the given js functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you have to convert javascript code into c#

You may use the [OpenAPI](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) to create a REST api methods and objects definitions.

Then there are tools to generate C# client|server stubs and Dto classes. Like the [Swagger codegen](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) or [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com)

This is the very good way to have REST API definition. Then you can share this definition between different teams|projects.

Or you may try the [following dynamic deserialization approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806407/940182)

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

it allows to get dynamic object from the json string.

I suppose that you can even create code that will parse path are being requested by the `Javascript code` but there are the holy [ASP.NET Web APIs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis) implemented already.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a tutorial on how to generate an openAPI specification for an api from javascript code using c#?

Comment: @EmanAbdelmohsen I do not know the way how to build openAPI from jsvascript code. It works in the opposite way usually